# How can I unduplicate my commits?

Tags: git, github

While trying to use git filter-branch, I duplicated several commits [here](https://github.com/Nathan2055/afch/commits/master). How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you did?

Comment: @poke - I ran `git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Nathan2055'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='nathan2055@private.fake'; GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='Nathan2055'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='nathan2055@private.fake';" HEAD`. When I tried to push, it said I needed to do a pull first for some reason. I did the pull, and it came up with needing to merge. I did a commit like it said, and then pushed. Now it's all messed up.

Comment: note that the only thing you did wrong (given your objective) was that you did not do `git push -f`. It asked you to pull first (mistake) because your local branch and the remote did not share any history (which is entirely correct if you just rewrote history using git-filter-branch). In future please add information to the *question* don't comment with significant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING:**
The following commands will lose all commits past `d4f81a8` and any uncommitted local changes.

```
git reset --hard d4f81a8fff53cbbaabfdf6980fa68bf44e8d77f5
git push --force origin
```

The problem is that `git filter-branch` created an entirely separate chain of commits. When you tried to push to the server git refused because the new head was not a descendant of the server's head. The push would lose the commits in the chain leading up to the old head, which is normally something you want to avoid. However in this case the new chain is a copy of the old chain, so no content is lost.

The first command, `git reset`, undoes the merge by setting the master branch's head to the last commit in the new chain. The merge was not appropriate because the chains already had the same content, making the old chain redundant. The `--hard` option also resets the index and the working directory to that commit.

The `--force` option to `git push` tells git to ignore the fact that the new head is not a descendant of the old one. Again, this is very dangerous because it will lose the commits in the old chain. To check that there is nothing new on the server you can use `git fetch`, which will download the commits from the server to the ref `FETCH_HEAD` but unlike `git pull` it will not automatically merge. That way you can compare your commit to the latest one on the server and double check that nothing is missing.

Comment: Very well, I will add a warning.

Comment: The --hard is also unnecessary anyway.

Comment: @Kzqai It is necessary, because the working directory needs to be updated.

Comment: @Kzqai The reflog can be used to recover the head commit (though not the working directory). If you have an alternative which provides more safety, please share.

Comment: +1 – this is indeed the right solution for this situation. A short explanation of what the commands do, why they apply to this situation and what OP did wrong to end up in this situation would be nice, though.

Comment: @Chronial Thanks for the suggestion. I added an explanation (open to improvements).

Comment: +1 assuming that yields the [right history for the repository](https://github.com/Nathan2055/afch/commits/d4f81a8fff53cbbaabfdf6980fa68bf44e8d77f5). [It looks like it](https://github.com/Nathan2055/afch/commit/d4f81a8fff53cbbaabfdf6980fa68bf44e8d77f5.patch). Would perhaps be better to show using the ref-log how to determine which commit to reset to.

Comment: I personally don’t like the reflog for that – I tend to use `gitk --all`.